# Error when connecting from a web server to a remote MySQL DB Server

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I have been struggling to connect from  a Ubuntu version 16.04 web server 
(running on 1  AWS instance, with PHP 7.0.33 and Apache 2.7.18)
communicating with a data base server using MySQL 8.0.19 running on another AWS instance (running Ubuntu version 16.04).

I set up the data base server and configured it as follows:

I edit the file  /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

I add the following in the [mysqld] section
     [mysqld]

```
require_secure_transport = on
```

I save the file and from the console issue:

```
sudo mysql_ssl_rsa_setup --uid=mysql
```

I then restart mysql with:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

I have created a data base and tables on this data base server.

I also created a remote user on this data base server as follows (IP address and user are fictitious):

```
CREATE USER 'Master'@'1.26.4.44' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sample_data_base.* TO ' Master'@'1.26.4.44';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Exit
```

I successfully test the connectivity to this db server from the web server client instance:

```
mysql -u Master -p   -h '1.26.4.44'
```

However when I use the following PHP code snippet from the web server client instance
to open the connection to the data base server, I get an error (see below):

```
// set up for  remote DB access     
  $dbhost  = '1.26.4.44';    // Unlikely to require changing
  $dbname  = 'sample_data_base';   // Modify these...
  $dbuser  = 'Master';   // ...variables according
  $dbpass  = "admin";   // ...to your installation
  $appname = "test_app"; // ...and preference

$dbconnection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

   if ( !$dbconnection) 
  {
      echo "connection failed   ";
      die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
```

The error is:

```
Connect Error (3159) Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON
```

Just as an FYI,  when I comment out the line on the data base server in the
file  /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

```
# require_secure_transport = on
```

There are no issues with the php code connection to the remote data base server.

What am I missing on the web server client side to let me connect to the remote db server from the php code?

Comment: useful article: https://medium.com/@kristi.anderson/configuring-and-managing-ssl-on-your-mysql-server-735bbe67955d

Answer (score 1):

You need extra configurations in your db setup:

```
$db = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options ($db, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

$db->ssl_set(
    '/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem',
    '/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem',
    '/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem',
    NULL,
    NULL);

$link = mysqli_real_connect(
        $db, 'ip', 'user', 'password', 'db', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

if (!$link)
{
    die ('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '): ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
} else {
    // your queries should be here
     $db->close();
}
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Mirdrack - I made the mods you suggested to the code on the web server but I get:    
  connection failed Connect error (2002):

Comment: Is there some set up I need to do on the web server (client)  for the client-key files shown in thee ssl_set function call?

Comment: 2002 error normally means that there is no MySQL server running on the system or that you are using an incorrect port
Are you able to connected through localhost?

Comment: In the post at  https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-enable-ssl-and-remote-connections-for-mysql-on-centos-7/   it makes it seem as if I need to configure the db server and the web server client with the ssl certificates.  My config file in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf    on the db server shows:  [mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
#require_secure_transport = on

Comment: The issue has been fixed.   I used the following:  a.   Removed the mysqli_options line.  b.  replace  in the the call to mysqli_real_connect   the MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL  option with  MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT     Found that this was also reported by other developers who ran into similar problems.    Thank you for the help.